# SQL query for the store with the minimum price of an item in the city

Tags: sql, subquery

I have this table

(city,storeID,itemID,price)

I need to return  for each city,itemID the storeID with the minimum price for the item  and the minimum price itself ( city,itemID,storeIDmin,minprice).

Can someone help me with this query ?

Thanks!

Comment: Are using MSSQL or MySQL or something else? The answer and approach could depend on this.

Comment: What happens when two stores have the same price for a given item? Return both, or just one? If one, which one (or random)?

Comment: This is for school HW - standard SQL is what we use. If   two stores have the same price for a given item return any random one of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this with Join and Subquery (Also possible to use "WITH AS" Clause if you work on oracle DB):

```
SELECT table1.city, table1.itemID, table1.storeID as storeIDmin, subquery.min_price 
FROM table1
JOIN (select city, itemID, min(price) as min_price from table1 
group by city,itemID) AS subquery
ON table1.city = subquery.city
AND table1.itemID = subqueryitemID
AND table1.price = 
subquery.min_price
```

the result for example:

```
+------+---------+--------+-------+
| city | storeID | itemID | price |
+------+---------+--------+-------+
|    1 |       1 |      1 |    70 |
|    1 |       2 |      1 |    60 |
|    2 |       1 |      1 |   100 |
|    2 |       1 |      2 |    90 |
|    2 |       2 |      1 |    88 |
|    3 |       1 |      1 |    70 |
+------+---------+--------+-------+
```

will result:

```
+------+--------+----------+-------+
| city | itemID | storeMin | price |
+------+--------+----------+-------+
|    2 |      1 |        1 |   88 |
|    3 |      1 |        1 |    70 |
|    2 |      2 |        1 |    90 |
|    1 |      1 |        2 |    60 |
+------+--------+----------+-------+
```

Comment: AND table1.itemID = table1.itemID did you  mean table1.itemID = subquery.itemID ?

Comment: excatly! sorry for this mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.price = (select min(t2.price) from t t2 where t2.itemId = t.itemId);
```

Comment: select t.*
from t
where t.price = (select min(t2.price) from t t2 where t2.itemId = t.itemId and t.city = t2.city); I think you forgot the  t.city = t2.city

Comment: Note that this will return multiple stores if they have the same price (the only filtering is on price, so if two have the same, it will return 2 rows).